# Adding in react components to a next js Project

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've been trying to add certain components from my React project to me Next js project.
I'm getting an error with a certain component saying:

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `TableContainer`.

The component corresponding to this is:

```
 - TableContainer.js

  

  import React, { Fragment } from "react";
    import classes from './TableContainer.module.css';
    import {
      useTable,
      useGlobalFilter,
      useSortBy,
      useFilters,
      useExpanded,
      usePagination,
    } from "react-table";
    import { Table, Row, Col, Button, Input, CustomInput } from "reactstrap";
    import { Filter, DefaultColumnFilter } from "./filters";
    import { GlobalFilter } from "./GlobalFilter";
        
        const TableContainer = ({ columns, data, renderRowSubComponent }) => {
          const {
            getTableProps,
            getTableBodyProps,
            headerGroups,
            page,
            prepareRow,
            visibleColumns,
            canPreviousPage,
            canNextPage,
            pageOptions,
            pageCount,
            gotoPage,
            nextPage,
            previousPage,
            setPageSize,
            state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
            state,
            setGlobalFilter,
          } = useTable(
            {
              columns,
              data,
              defaultColumn: { Filter: DefaultColumnFilter },
              initialState: { pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 20 },
            }, 
            useGlobalFilter,
            useFilters,
            useSortBy,
            useExpanded,
            usePagination
          );
        
          const {globalFilter} = state
        
          const generateSortingIndicator = (column) => {
            return column.isSorted ? (column.isSortedDesc ? " " : " ") : "";
          };
        
          const onChangeInSelect = (event) => {
            setPageSize(Number(event.target.value));
          };
        
          const onChangeInInput = (event) => {
            const page = event.target.value ? Number(event.target.value) - 1 : 0;
            gotoPage(page);
          };
        
          return (
            <div>
              <GlobalFilter filter={globalFilter} setFilter={setGlobalFilter}/>
            {/* <Fragment> */}
              <div className="data">
                <div className="up">
                {/* <Table className="dataheading">
                
                 {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                   <tr>
                     {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                       <th>
                         <Filter column={column} />
                       </th>
                     ))}
                   </tr>
                 ))}
                
                </Table> */}
                </div>
              <Table bordered hover {...getTableProps()}>
                <thead>
                 
                  {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                    <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                      {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                        <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                          <div {...column.getSortByToggleProps()}>
                            {column.render("Header")}
                            {generateSortingIndicator(column)}
                          </div>
                          <Filter column={column} />
                        </th>
                      ))}
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                  
                </thead>
                {/* <div  className="data"> */}
                <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()} style={{ minWidth: 200}}>
                  {page.map((row) => {
                    prepareRow(row);
                    return (
                      <Fragment key={row.getRowProps().key}>
                        <tr>
                          {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                            return (
                              <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                            );
                          })}
                        </tr>
                        {row.isExpanded && (
                          <tr>
                            <td colSpan={visibleColumns.length}>
                              {renderRowSubComponent(row)}
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        )}
                      </Fragment>
                      
                    );
                  })}
                </tbody>
                {/* </div> */}
              </Table>
              
              </div>
              
              <div className="footer">
                <div className="footer-data">
                <Row style={{ maxWidth: 800, minWidth: 200,margin: "0 auto", textAlign: "center" }}>
                  <Col>
                    {/* <Button
                    color='primary'
                    onClick={() => gotoPage(0)}
                    disabled={!canPreviousPage}
                  >
                    {'<<'}
                  </Button> */}
                    <Button
                      color="danger"
                      onClick={previousPage}
                      disabled={!canPreviousPage}
                    >
                      {"<"}
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                  <Col style={{ marginTop: 7 }}>
                    Page{" "}
                    <strong>
                      {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
                    </strong>
                  </Col>
                  <Col>
                    <Input
                      type="number"
                      min={1}
                      style={{ width: 70}}
                      max={pageOptions.length}
                      defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
                      onChange={onChangeInInput}
                    />
                  </Col>
                  <Col>
                    <CustomInput
                      type="select"
                      value={pageSize}
                      onChange={onChangeInSelect}
                    >
                      {[20, 30, 40, 50].map((pageSize) => (
                        <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
                          Show {pageSize}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                    </CustomInput>
                  </Col>
                  <Col >
                    <Button color="danger" onClick={nextPage} disabled={!canNextPage}>
                      {">"}
                    </Button>
                    {/* <Button
                    color='primary'
                    onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)}
                    disabled={!canNextPage}
                  >
                    {'>>'}
                  </Button> */}
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        };
        export default TableContainer;
```

---

Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Please list down the external components used - like GlobalFilter, Filter, DefaultColumnFilter. And, try to show how each of these have been exported.

Comment: Maybe you should post the full error stack messages.